# How to use Microsoft flow to assign the task to a group?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

How can we use Microsoft flow to assign a task to sharepoint group in task list field of type person or group. I am able to assign a task to an individual but can not assign a task to a group. I am using the create item action in the microsoft flow to create new tasks.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible, but there are 2 things you should check before you will be able to add a group to a Person or Group field in Microsoft Flow.

1. Make sure you allow groups to be selected in the Person or Group field settings as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPvuC.png).
2. The group you want to select should be created in the same site level as you are trying to make the new task in. E.g. If your tasks list is on a subsite, you should create your group in that same subsite to be able to select the group in your Microsoft Flow 'Create item' action.

I hope this works out for you!

Comment: Could you please provide a bigger screenshot or describe how to get to this setting you mentioned in point 1? I have no idea how to find it :/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried in this context but you can still do "groups" when sending an email I know. It is not an option when you start typing like people are but if you go to Outlook and create an email and select that group to send to and then copy the email address it would go to and then paste that in Flow it will send it to that group. Might try that for your scenario also.